# Compare two, 2D Array paired string elements regardless of order for differences within Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

**Problem**

1. I would like to compare **every paired elements** (if that is a thing) such as `[[Store 1, A, 1]]` from sheet 1 to sheet 2, and have an array return that only has which pairs did not match. I'm not attempting to see if any element from one array is one the other array, I want to see if the paired elements are within the other array regardless of the order, just the contents being the same. For example on sheet 1 I have `[Store 2, 2, B]` and Sheet 2 I have `[Store 2, B, 2]` and this would be a match.
2. I will then ideally access this new array to pull out each item for further use in further coding such as the `Store` or the `Location` from this new array. I'm assuming a 2-day array would be ideal for this.
3. **The arrays will not be the same length, unlike my example. Sheet 2 would have more data. I simplified it for this example.** I mention this as I've read some solutions comparing arrays but the lengths have to be the same.

Is it possible to do #1, if yes any help/advice would be appreciated!

**Data Explanation**

I have 2 sheets, the columns are the same but in different locations. Sheet 1 will remain constant, while sheet 2 is obtaining new data. In this example, sheet 1 is let's say our master/refer to data source, so sheet 2 should match the row/elements on it. See tables below for an example of a row/elements that match such as row 3 from sheet 1 (store 2, 2, b).

Store names will repeat as will locations, however **store # will be unique and not repeat** for each array/sheet. An example would be, we could have 5 Store 1's, with 5 different store numbers. There would not be 5 stores 1's, with the same store # and location.

**Current Output**

sheet 1 array:

[image]

`[["Store 1",2,"A"],["Store 2",2,"B"],["Store 1",1,"D"],["Store 1",3,"E"],["Store 3",4,"C"],["Store 4",1,"C"],["","",""]]`

sheet 2 array:

[image]

`[["Store 1","A",1],["Store 2","B",2],["Store 1","D",1],["Store 1","E",3],["Store 3","C",4],["Store 4","C",2],["","",""]]`

result of filter function:

[image]

`[]`

**Desired Output**

`[["Store 1", 2, "A"] , ["Store 4", 1, "C"]]`

**Solutions tried**

1. Attempted to find a similar problem on stackoverflow, was unable to find my exact issue
2. Reviewed similar questions to mine to see if somewhat similar solutions would work (see references below). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792141/filter-a-2d-array-from-elements-of-another) question seemed promising, but the filter function seems to only work with number elements and not strings like I have. So if my arrays were `[[0,1,2]]` and `[[0,],[1]]` the filter method I have would work.
3. Attempted to use a `for` loop similar to the questions I've linked, but this is resulting in null answers
4. attempted to use the `filter` and `find` methods from similar answers but this also seemed unable to help me reach my desired outcome
5. reviewed on https://developer.mozilla.org/ if perhaps `Object.keys()` or `Object.entries()` would suffice, but that will not work since ideally we're using the elements in a pair as opposed to individual entries
6. Tried to use `JSON.stringify()` to turn the elements in the arrays into `strings`...however after further research it seems the items in the array are already strings? Also using `JSON.stringify()` only allows for certain methods (`search` and `match`) to be utilized so this did not seem feasible
7. Unable I think to utilize `flat()` to deconstruct the 2d into a 1d since I want the elements to stay grouped instead of being isolated.

**Current Code**

```js
function test() {
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var1 = ss1.getRange(2,1,ss1.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
  var2 =  ss2.getRange(2,1,ss1.getLastRow(),3).getValues();

  var test1= var1.filter(a => !var2.find(b => b[0] === a[0]))//returns [] at the moment, via the answer @Akrion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792141/filter-a-2d-array-from-elements-of-another

  var testR = new Array();

    for (var i=0;i<var1.length;i++){
      for (var j=0;j<var1.legnth;j++){
        if(var1[i][j]=!var2[i][j]){
         testR.push(var1[i]);
        }
        }
        }
        //for loop results in null at the moment, from question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596934/compare-multi-dimentional-arrays-in-javascript) and answer of @daiscog


}
```

**Raw Data Example**

Sheet 1:

| Store | Store # | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Store 1 | 2 | A |
| Store 2 | 2 | B |
| Store 1 | 1 | D |
| Store 1 | 3 | E |
| Store 3 | 4 | C |
| Store 4 | 1 | C |

Sheet 2:

| Store | Location | store # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Store 1 | A | 1 |
| Store 2 | B | 2 |
| Store 1 | D | 1 |
| Store 1 | E | 3 |
| Store 3 | C | 4 |
| Store 4 | C | 2 |

**Similar Questions**

1. [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript?rq=1)
2. [Compare multi dimentional arrays in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596934/compare-multi-dimentional-arrays-in-javascript)
3. [App Script / Javascript filter an array with another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291984/app-script-javascript-filter-an-array-with-another-array)
4. [Filter a 2D Array From Elements of Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792141/filter-a-2d-array-from-elements-of-another)

Comment: Avoid images of text. It would be great, if you provide `sheet 1 array: and sheet 2 array:` as plain text. Also use `console.log()` instead of `Logger`.

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(array))`  in the future. It's easier to copy paste directly in code. Right now, we have to quote all the strings. For eg, `[Store 1, 2.0, A]`  should be `["Store 1", 2.0, "A"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a array of [`Sets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from the second array and,
- Filter in arrays of first array, if it doesn't contain every element in some of the second array `Set`s

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const arr1 = [
    ['Store 1', 2, 'A'],
    ['Store 4', 1, 'C'],
    ['Store 2', 'A', 2],
    ['C', 'Store 3', 1],
  ],
  arr2 = [
    ['Store 2', 2, 'A', 3],
    ['Store 3', 1, 'C', 9],
  ],
  arr2Set = arr2.map((row) => new Set(row)),
  out = arr1.filter(
    (row) => !arr2Set.some((set) => row.every((el) => set.has(el)))
  );
console.log(out);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you @TheMaster, always help! Maybe a dumb question, but for the `arr2` would I have to type in the array into the script, or can I just grab the array with `.getValues`?

Comment: @User1938985 Why would I make you type it? Grab it with `getValues()`. This is just a demonstration here with a runnable code in-browser, "mocking" the actual values in sheet.

Answer (score 3):

Can't speak for the elegance or speed of this, but taking some inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872317), one way to do it would be to first swap the `B` and `C` columns from Sheet 2 to match the ones in Sheet 1, then use the [stringify way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript) to compare both arrays.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var var1 = ss1.getRange(2,1,ss1.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();
  var var2 = ss2.getRange(2,1,ss2.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();

  //swaps positions and returns a stringified array
  var2 = var2.map(x=>JSON.stringify([x[0], x[1], x[2]] = [x[0], x[2], x[1]]))
  
  //stringifies each element in var1 before matching to var2
  var output = var1.filter(x => !var2.includes(JSON.stringify(x)));

  console.log(output)
}
```

Output: `[ [ 'Store 1', 2, 'A' ], [ 'Store 4', 1, 'C' ] ]`

Comment: I thought that `ss1.getLastRow()` of `var var2 = ss2.getRange(2,1,ss1.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();` might be `ss2.getLastRow()`.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, you're right, I missed that. It's corrected now.

Comment: incredible thank you, I wasn't quite sure if this was possible but this makes sense!

Comment: 1. I thought OP said any order... not just  B <--> C 2. OP also said different number of elements(not just 3). I think your code will fail both those criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the code from [this](https://github.com/NikolaPlusEqual/GAS-advanced-range-comparison) repository, which is the code in [my Github repository](https://github.com/NikolaPlusEqual) I submited to Github this morning. The `permutator()` function is provided by user [delimited](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2631343/delimited) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871714/).

The current code is not protected with any kind of licence. The Github link is submitted because I also developed 3 more functions, for cases that user want to get array of values where condition is satisfied, or array of rows number in the sheet (where criteria is met or no) as well:

```
var setData = {};

function findNotEqualContent(shorterArr, longerArr){
  setData.arr2 = longerArr;
  var output = shorterArr.filter(neq);
  return output;
}

function neq(ar){
  var res = true;
  var permutationArr = setData.arr2;
  permutationArr.forEach(function(item){
    var tempArr = permutator(item);
    tempArr.forEach(function (temp){
      if (temp.toString().slice(0, (ar.toString().length)) == ar.toString()){
        res = false;
      }
    });
  });
  return res;
}
```

> ```
> ////// SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871714 by user delimited https://stackoverflow.com/users/2631343/delimited 
> function permutator(inputArr) {
>  var results = [];
>  function permute(arr, memo) {
>    var cur, memo = memo || [];
>
>    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
>      cur = arr.splice(i, 1);
>      if (arr.length === 0) {
>        results.push(memo.concat(cur));
>      }
>      permute(arr.slice(), memo.concat(cur));
>      arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]);
>    }
>    return results;
>  }
>  return permute(inputArr);
> }
> ```

and test it this way:

```
function testArrays(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var rng1 = ss1.getRange(2,1,ss1.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
  var rng2 = ss2.getRange(2,1,ss1.getLastRow(),5).getValues();
  output = findNotEqualContent(rng1,rng2);
  Logger.log(output);
}
```